# Favor breaking up big commands into smaller ones if not actually necessary at present time?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am implementing backend for some shop, that is fully written on frontend and only final state (data) are sent to backend. I am trying to use DDD with CQRS/ES.

Happy scenario usecase (for example, generalized):

- Given that User, Cart and CartItem exists.
- User can add CartItem of type X to cart
- User can specify (set some params) of CartItem Y
- User can add CartItem of type Y
- User can choose address from his adresses (creating them is concern
  of another BC)
- User can Place Order

Now, because this all happens on Frontend, my only delivery mechanism now is some raw data from GraphQL. Should I have in Application layer some CreateNewOrderFromGraphQL with method create($someGraphQLData); that just creates relatively big CreateNewOrderCommand (because it needs to contain adress, CartItems, promo code etc) and passes it through command bus into my domain model that creates whole order?

Or should I think about my domain model same way as it is done on frontend  and so then in my CreateNewOrderFromGraphQL break big raw GraphQL data into separate commands like CreateCartCommand, AddItemToCartCommand, CreateOrderCommand (which would consist of cart id, adress id, and maybe some details) and then call them in sequence?

What considerations should I take on that?

Comment: What are your invariants? In what conditions an `Order` can be created and placed? You should create commands based on your `Aggregate's` invariants.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Order can be created if: 1) User of given id exists 2) Adress of given id exists 3) Cart is valid, it means each CartItem in order's Cart passed theirs own invariants. So, I suppose it is more wise to break that, so I can create cart first, then add items one after one and in the end just pass id of that cart to order. Then I can possibly eventually report error on specific item (but everything else can process ok) while creating cart (and possibly in many steps) instead of disallowing to "create whole order with everything given"?

Comment: You have no control over the frontend? Because ideally with DDD your user's intent corresponds with actions in the UI all the way to the backend. If you can't do that, I would indeed try to work as if you could, and create a facade for your frontend that makes the frontend look as if it was generating commands itself. With some luck one day the frontend can then be updated / upgraded to the ideal situation, but if not, your backend won't suffer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have many behavior in the front-end and the front-end can't be trusted you are forced to duplicate behavior in the back-end as well.
So, let's see what you have here.

I think that you should design your domain model (the command side) to be UI agnostic, where the GraphQL interface is a kind of UI.

So, if a user exists is a check that you already have to do, in the authorization phase of the request. If a user does not exist then the client request should not reach the domain model, it should be denied by the application layer (or similar layer that is between the UI and the domain).

The cart could be done as another `Aggregate`. It should have commands like `CreateCartCommand` and `AddItemToCartCommand`. Or it could be done as CRUD, if there are no real invariants.

Then, the `OrderAggregate` could have a `PlaceOrderCommand`, with items  from cart as arguments and an `AddressId` and `UserId` that are already checked for existence by the Application layer. This `Aggregate` protects it's own invariants, like `total price <= some max value` or check inventory status (in case inventory is not in another BC).